# Why is vim turning map <M-o> into strange character ï

Tags: ubuntu, vim, ubuntu-14.04, parallels

I have the following map command in my `~/.vimrc` that I've used for years:

`map <M-o> :split<Space>`

It works well when I use it in OS X, Ubuntu, even when running Ubuntu in a Parallels Desktop VM. However, I just installed a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.2 on a VM using Parallels on my mac OS X Yosemite. When I copied the same `.vimrc` to the VM, when I run vim or gvim, pressing `M-o` doesn't work at all.

If I type `:map` inside vim running in the VM I see the following:

`ï             :split<Space>`

If I do it inside, say, MacVim or just vim on my Mac or any other OS where it does work I see the following:

`<M-o>         :split<Space>`

Why is `<M-o>` being turned into `ï`? What gives, I tried setting:

`set encoding=utf-8`

in my `.vimrc` but it doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: The original meaning of "Meta" was to turn on the high-order bit. In Latin-1 and Unicode, the codes for `'o'` and `'ï'` are `0x6f` and `0xef`, respectively. That doesn't entirely explain the behavior you're seeing (which is why this is a comment, not an answer), but you might take a look at your locale settings.

Comment: This is between your terminal and the `readline` library.  For `xterm` see the `VT100*metaSendsEscape` resource.  See also the `*-meta` settings in your `inputrc`.